# Firefox white flash before website loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a PHP/HTML/Javascript site. The frontend loads data with Javascript. I am seeing only in Firefox I see a brief white flash of the page before it loads. In all other browsers this does not happen. I am new to debugging Javascript - and even notice in Firefox inspector tools I don't even have an option to break an element on break-point which is pretty frustrating - so just seeing if anyone smarter than me with JS could offer some pointers or where to start debugging this Firefox only issue I am experiencing.

I am noticing it has to do with `window.location` being served to redirect the user to a new screen after searching. Does Firefox has something goofy related to window.location loading that I am not aware of?

Comment: " break an element on break-point" what does that mean? It sounds like you are trying to load content but the data hasn't been received from the server. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Comment: i am getting closer to figuring it out. i will edit my question with more detaill

Comment: can you post some code?